# Loading multiple SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', functionname);

Tags: spservices

Share experience

As recommended in various posts I changed the way the functions load from

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   functionName();
});
```

to

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', functionname);
```

Works great with the following expection:

I have several pages where several webparts each load a separate `SP.SOD.executeFunc()`. One webpart loads a  `SP.SOD.executeFunc()` that creates a JumboTron then below it a different webpart loads three  `SP.SOD.executeFunc()`s to create three columns of output.

Not a problem for Chrome but it appears that IE 11 does not like `SP.SOD.executeFunc()` loads spanning webparts as the Jumbotron loads but  the three columns fails - no error just does not excute. I had to create a new webpart that loaded all the `SP.SOD.executeFunc()`s in order to work in IE 11.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', functionjumbotron);
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', functioncolumn1);
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', functioncolumn2);
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', functioncolumn3);
```

Question is there another way to load these so it can span webparts?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Please update about the resolution if you get it.

Comment: Yes I placed all the SP.SOD in a single webpart at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Is that works for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is the basic implementation of LoadSodByKey, this is the best implementation of the function as it has the override to allow you to have a callback for when the script is loaded.

After jquery is loaded, the anonymous function will write "Hello World" to the console

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   LoadSodByKey("js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js", function () {
       console.log("Hello world!")
   });
</script>
```

These are my thus far best practices for loading and using scripts, and I will continue to update this post as time goes on, and understanding of this increases.

OR you can use below

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(someFunction,"sp.js");
```

**UPDATE**

A full working compatible pattern for doing this is: Note the called JS file needs to be registered, and run the Notify SOD command

```
// Callback method
var callback = function () {
    // Code goes here
};

// Expected namespace after loaded
var namespace = "SP.RequestExecutor";

// SOD Key of target js file
var key = "sp.requestexecutor.js";

// Load straight away, or in queue
var bSync = false;

SP.SOD.executeFunc(key, namespace, function () {
    console.log(key + ": Type available (" + namespace + ")");
}, bSync);

// Execute when script has notified loading (Event call)
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(callback, key);
```

Comment: Did you get it working? Did my answer helps you?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You were a big help as I was able to get it to run.

Comment: So kindly mark it so others can get benefit of it.

Comment: As well as give some credit to my answer by upvoting it.

Comment: Please bare with me as I'm new to this

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct So other users can trust the solution & get the help from it

Comment: That was the only this important

Comment: Hi Can you explain the answer? I have multiple methods which i need to call on the page so will I have to reload the sp.js and SP.ClientContext multiple times? or if one time its needed how will I do it through JS? I can ask this as a separate question but wanted suggestion if this is relevant to this question?